# Why is animating an element breaking the stacking context of associated pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element, css-animations

When I'm animating an element that has associated ::before and ::after generated content, the generated content, which was previously negative z-indexed, appears to become indexed higher than my original element. I'm seeing this in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

I know that's confusing, so [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Qh5/13/).

Any ideas where I'm going wrong, or if I've run into a bug?

Comment: does not work in IE9 on Windows 7. Still has Z-index -01

Comment: Interesting, so the green box stays on top the entire time in W7 IE9? Anything to suggest this is actually a browser bug and not me being crazy is great.

Comment: no idea mate. Z-index is -1 at all times and green box stays where it is on W7 in IE9.

Comment: z-index set in the div css appears to be ignored or something in Safari mobile. Setting div.z-index:1; moves it behind the before and after, permanently, although the <p> stays on top. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph text stays on top. Maybe wrap the "p" in another "div" and see if it persists w/ a wrapper.  http://jsfiddle.net/q7Qh5/17/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, chovy. In the end, I'm gonna chalk this up to a browser bug, but this is a nice suggested workaround in the interim. Thanks!